# OSM PMTiles at scale

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to serve a dynamic map of Europe to MapLibre on the front which has the following characteristics:

### Features

- the map is based on a full OSM data extract (with streets, POIs etc.)
- the map allows zooming up to level 20
- the entire map must be updated once a week

### Usage

- Users of the map can connect from Dublin, London, Paris, Milano, Madrid, Lisboa, Berlin, Budapest, and Bucharest.
- They browse the map within a 500km area.

We know that the front-end server located in Berlin handles these max volumes:

- 50 map loads and zoom within the same time 3-min period
- 300 map loads and zoom within the same hour

### Question

Is it possible to handle this load using PMTiles?